# Sparse representation data file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python and I have a file in the following format:

```
2:10 13:1 17:6 21:10
3:11 131:12
...
```

Each row consists of elements of the form `column:value`. In the example, this means that the first row should consist 10 in the second column, 1 in the 13th and so on. EDIT: Each row in the data correspond to a row in the matrix

Is that a format that python knows how to convert to a sparse matrix? (in order to perform PCA for example) or must I build the matrix by myself?

Comment: So if you have the coordinate of columns how you want to set a row coordinate for your values?

Comment: No headers at all? no row info?

Comment: @gboffi: Each row in the data correspond to a row in the matrix. I've made an edit.

Comment: How do you know the number of columns? is it a square matrix? divination?

Comment: @gboffi: By the maximum value of the key. But let's say that I know it in advnance.

Comment: so, you're trying to create a kind of 'dynamic matrix' with a known rows count but an undefined columns count?

Comment: @AboudZakaria: For simlicity let's assume that the number of columns is fixed. The 'dynamic matrix' is not important at the moment. I'm trying to represent this object as a sparse python matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the following assumptions

1. the file has as many rows as the matrix you're reading
2. there is the possibility that one file's row is empty
3. the matrix is square
4. the column indices in the data file start from 1

and I'm using the module `scipy.sparse`

```
from scipy import sparse

I, J, V = [], [], []

for i, line in enumerate(open(datafile)):
    for j, v in [map(int,item.split(':')) for item in line.split()]:
        I.append(i) ; J.append(j-1) ; V.append(v)
A = sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)), shape=(i+1,i+1)
print A.todense()
```

with the following data

```
1:2 3:4


2:5
```

the above code prints

```
[[2 0 4 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 5 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this task memory efficient and performant, check out the [Collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) library, and in particular [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). You'll only store data values that have a corresponding column (key). The data will no longer be a 'matrix', but that means you don't have to store non-existent values.

(notice that I added '2:11' to your data, so that one column would have more than one value)

```
from collections import defaultdict    
d = defaultdict(list)    

data = '2:10 13:1 17:6 21:10 3:11 131:12 2:11'.split()

for x in data:
    k = x.split(':')[0]
    v = x.split(':')[1]

    d[k].append(v)

print d
```

gives the output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'13': ['1'], '21': ['10'], '17': ['6'], '3': ['11'], '131': ['12'], '2': ['10','11]})
```

In this case, you only store the columns (dictionary keys) that have values.